# Logout button doesn't show unless i Refresh browser

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I created a Register/Login Page with React and Node.js I implemented a Logout button, everything works fine, but when I login or register a user I have to refresh the browser before the logout button shows. I don't understand why it doesn't show immediately when I login or register a user, unless I refresh the browser.

What can I do to solve this?

Comment: Nobody can tell you what's wrong with code we can't see.  Please provide a [mcve] demonstrating the problem.  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

make sure that your `setState()` is called with the user data after a successful login; and your `useEffect()` is written properly to make effect of a state change, and update UI accordingly.